# Destroy Thread with 'aborted' state

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Using background worker in a winform program. Also communicating with somedevices
I have a stop button which tries to stop the background worker thread, which works, but sometimes, the background worker thread remains in state "Aborted"

I have to mention that I take care about the exception that rise, and also use a 'Finally' block to stop the communication with the devices

I need to stop the thread immediately, something like an emergency button...

Some code:

```
Private Sub BtnStopTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStopTest.Click
        Try

            stoppedTesting = True
            Log("Stopping operations safely. (You might have to wait some time )", Color.Blue, New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Bold))

            If bgWorkThread IsNot Nothing Then
                'stop thread

                'if thread is sleeping (waiting for a time)
                If bgWorkThread.ThreadState = ThreadState.Background + ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin Then
                    bgWorkThread.Interrupt()
                Else 'if thread is working normally
                    bgWorker.CancelAsync()
                    tEO.DoWorkEventArgs.cancel = True
                    bgWorkThread.Abort()
                  'sometimes, here the Thread has state 'Aborted

                End If
            ElseIf bgWorkThread Is Nothing Then
                Dim ee As New System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs(New Object, Nothing, False)

                BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(New Object, ee)

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Utils.PreserveStackTrace(ex)
            Log("Error when stopping testing" & vbCrLf & Utils.ReadException(ex), MessageType.ErrorMessage)
        End Try
    End Sub





  Private Sub BgWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.DoWork
        Try

        'some other things to do
        For Each testStep In stepList

                Try
                'main operations and communication with device
                ' below functions are all different 
                'something like:
                'CommunicationWithDevice1()
                'CommunicationWithDevice2()
                'CommunicationWithDevice3()
                'CommunicationWithDevice4()
                '....
                'CommunicationWithDevice20()

                Catch ex As Exception When TypeOf ex Is ThreadAbortException OrElse TypeOf ex Is ThreadInterruptedException
                    Utils.PreserveStackTrace(ex)
                    Log("Exception in thread" & vbCrLf & Utils.ReadException(ex), MessageType.ErrorMessage)

                    e.Cancel = True

                    If ex.GetType = GetType(ThreadAbortException) Then Thread.ResetAbort()
                    If stoppedTesting Then Exit For

                    Catch ex As Exception
                    If stoppedTesting Then Exit For
                End Try

                Catch ex As Exception When TypeOf ex Is ThreadAbortException OrElse TypeOf ex Is ThreadInterruptedException
            e.Cancel = True
            Log("Background worker thread was interrupted!")
            Log("Background worker thread was interrupted!", Color.Red, New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Bold))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Utils.PreserveStackTrace(ex)
            Log("Error when doing background work!" & vbCrLf & Utils.ReadException(ex), Color.Red, New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Bold))
        Finally
            StopCommunication()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

1. What can I do to completely destroy the thread?
2. If there is not possibility, any workaround to exit my 'DoWork' method immediately?

Comment: Ouch!  A Bgw uses a Pool thread, you shouldn't even alter any properties of it and certainly not Abort() it!

Comment: And you can't and shouldn't dispose or destroy Threads. They look after themselves.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ok... and do you have any ideas for an emergency stop of a thread?

Comment: Yes, avoid needing that. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2178607/) and many more. Thread.Abort() should be avoided for your own threads, calling it on a Pool thread is ... evil.

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()` does not cancel the thread immediately, it actually posts the STOP message on the queue as you can check the `BackgroundWorker.isCancellationPending` is set to true, if you want to cancel immediately, you could have a global **boolean** and set it if you can to cancel the thread. In your Do_Work() method, you can regularly check the boolean and if it is set, run `Exit Sub`.

Something like this should do

```
Else 'if thread is working normally
                    cancelThread = true
                    tEO.DoWorkEventArgs.cancel = True
```

and inside your Do_Work sub

```
For Each testStep In stepList

                Try
                 If cancelThread Then
                 Exit Sub
```

This will cleanly stop the **BackgroundWorker** and allow you to run the *RunWorkerCompleted* routine. Inside it, you can check for the **cancelThread** to know if the **BackgroundWorker** ran successfully or it was aborted.

**UPDATE 2**

After going through your code one more time, why do you need to use BackgroundWorker and Thread together? If you want immediate cancellation, use only Thread. Also, you only need one TRY..Catch for the entire function, that way it will ensure that the thread exits. You can always assign the thread to nothing and Garbage Collector will take care of freeing resources for you(If you are concerned with ABORTED)

```
Dim myThread As Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(yourFunctionForCommunication))
myThread.Start()
```

And in your function

```
Try

.. Do your work


Catch Ex As ThreadAbortException
Exit Sub;
Finally
//Do your cleanup code here
End Try
```

The abort call

```
myThread.Abort()
While mythread.ThreadState <> ThreadState.Aborted
End While
myThread = Nothing
```

But I should warn you that Aborting threads is not a safe process. See this [MSDN Post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx).

If you would still want to use Background worker, i would suggest you to look into `List<dynamic>`. Add all the `Communicatewithdevice1()....to 20()` there then use that in a loop, that way you would not have to write the If conditional 20 times. See the post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152415/a-list-of-dynamic-functions-and-dynamically-calling-them)

Comment: Yes.. I thought of this method.. But I am practically polluting the background worker thread with checks... Imagine, that I might have 20-30 checks, after each communication with the device... What I need is an emergency exit...

Comment: How do you call it polluting? @eltigre

Comment: are you not doing the communication in a loop? if so, it will get checked automatically

Comment: Yes... but when I loop **once**, I have: Coomunicate1(), Communicate2()....Communicate20(). And for this, I have to check 20 times if the boolean is set... And that's not a nice code

Comment: Then @eltigre update your question so i can provide a better solution, add the Communications part.

Comment: @eltigre Updated answer

Comment: my problem was, that even if I called the thread to abort, it didn't raised the ThreadAbortException, because I would have caught it. Instead, thread's state became 'Aborted' and then couldnt do anything. I use only background worker. bgWorkerThread is just the instance of the thread created by the bgWorker,

Comment: Just use Thread and ThreadStart instead of Worker. It works fine @eltigre